# How to create trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

How to create a trigger that automatically creates a specific tape ids based on the number of quantity of tapes inserted. The trigger name should be `trig_auto_spid`.
This means that in table `tapes`, the `BatDog` has `QTy=3` so in table `Tape_Spec_Id` `TapesId T1=TS1, TS2, TS3...`.
I hope I made myself clear to you...

Here's the flow:

> Table:tapes  Qty:3

equivalent in

> Table:Tape_Spec_ID
>
> TSpecID TS1, TS2, TS3...

Here are my two tables:

```
Tapes                                 
----------------------
TapesID   Title    Qty
T1      BatDog     3
T2      UnderCat   2
T3      IronMouse  1
T4      Boys Zone  1
T5      RoboCat    1


Tape_Specific_ID
----------------
TapesID TSpecID
     T1 TS1
     T1 TS2
     T1 TS3
     T2 TS4
     T2 TS5
     T3 TS6
     T4 TS7
     T5 TS8
```

I really don't have any idea what to do, any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just update the tape_specific_id from your application after you've inserted the row into tapes?

Comment: i dnt really know how to do it by just triggering..can u help me?

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't used mysql triggers. I answered only because I wanted you to think that do you really need the trigger to achieve your goal. If you just want to learn how to do it I recommend to check out the MySQL docs.

Comment: [Dpcs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) , Try it and lets know if you face any issues @NeilBryanCasinang

Comment: Is it a possibility for you to change your db schema? If yes then it would be much easier to use auto-generated id's in both tables.

Comment: @theunlucky:im sorry if i dnt know how to do it...i really dnt have any idea how to start..please bear with me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trig_auto_spid`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `trig_auto_spid` AFTER INSERT ON `tapes` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SELECT REPLACE(TSpecID, 'TS', '') INTO @counter 
        FROM Tape_Specific_ID 
        ORDER BY TSpecID DESC LIMIT 1;

        SET @loopCnt = @counter + new.qty; 
        WHILE (@counter <= @loopCnt) DO 
            INSERT INTO Tape_Specific_ID(TapesID, TSpecID) 
            VALUES (new.TapesID, CONCAT('TS', @counter)); 
            SET @counter:=@counter + 1;
        END WHILE; 
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: everytime i add new record in the tapes table for ex: TapesID:T9, Title:Coat, Qty:2, the tape_specific_ID should be added TapesID: T9 TSpecID:T10 and another TapesID: T9, TspecID: T11, i hope i made myself clear to you...but the problem is it wont add in tape_specific_id...

Comment: can u help me with my problem?

Comment: hey man!ive cleared all th errors...thanks..u r so brilliant..cheerS!